# Provide custom object instance to Jackson without TypeInfo

Tags: java, json, jackson, jackson-databind

I'm trying to deserialize some polymorphic objects using Jackson but I don't want to expose the type info in the JSON. So, let's say we have the "classic" Animals scenario:

```java
public interface Animal {
    String talk();
}

public class Dog implements Animal {
    public String talk() { return "Woof!"; }
}

public class Cat implements Animal {
    public String talk() { return "Meow!"; }
}
```

I also have a Factory interface, and multiple Factory implementations:

```java
public interface AnimalFactory {
    Animal newAnimal();
}

public class DogFactory implements AnimalFactory {
    public Animal newAnimal() { return new Dog(); }
}

public class CatFactory implements AnimalFactory {
    public Animal newAnimal() { return new Cat(); }
}
```

Since I don't want to pollute the JSON with implementation details by using `@JsonTypeInfo` and a `type` parameter in the JSON, I only know about two choices:

- Use `@JsonDeserialize(as = Dog.class)` on `Animal`, but this would require an explicit dependency from the API to the implementation class; moreover it would always deserialize the JSON as Dog, while I would like to find a suitable concrete implementation only at runtime because I don't know which concrete implementation will be available;
- Use a `StdDeserializer` subclass:

```java
public class AnimalDeserializer extends StdDeserializer<Animal> {

    // Obtain through dependency injection or other mechanism
    private AnimalFactory animalFactory;

    public AnimalDeserializer() {
        this(null);
    }

    public AnimalDeserializer(Class<Animal> vc) {
        super(vc);
    }

    @Override
    public Animal deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        return animalFactory.newAnimal();
    }
```

This approach would allow me to locate at runtime the implementation but it also requires me to manually set and get any field instead of relying in data binding (of course it would be trivial in this specific case, but my objects are quite complex and I also have many different interfaces, so I'd really need to rely on data binding).

So, my question is: do I have another way of manually providing a concrete `Animal` instance but then let Jackson to do its data binding magic instead of manually implement all of it? As a reference, in case someone have some experience with JAXB, something like `@XmlRegistry` where I can specify a factory for a given interface would be awesome.

Thanks!

EDIT: it wasn't that clear probably, but I don't want to put a `type` property in the JSON to be deserialized because I don't want to expose implementation details there, so `@JsonTypeInfo` is not an option unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@JsonTypeInfo` and `@JsonSubtypes` for automatically polymorphism support.

```
@JsonTypeInfo(
    use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME,
    include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY,
    property = "type")
@JsonSubTypes({
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Cat.class, name = "cat"),
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Dog.class, name = "dog")
})

public interface Animal {
    String talk();
}
```

Comment: But this way I would need to add a `type` property in my JSON, which is the very thing I want to avoid in the first place if you read the post :)

EDIT: I'll make the post more clear anyway, thanks for the feedback